# Do something with selected rows in a UITableView, using an IBAction (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'd like to be able to select one row or more, and with an IBAction do something.

Let's say I have four rows, A, B, C and D. If I select A and B, and press the button connected to that IBAction, something happens.

How do I go about this?

**Code:**

```
@implementation ViewController {

NSArray *names;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

return [names count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"tableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (indexPath.row == 2)) {

    NSLog(@"John and James selected.");

}


}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
// Initialize table data
names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Michael", @"Hannah", @"James", nil];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by pressing " IBAction"?

Comment: @SatishMavani I mean button, sorry. A button connected to that IBAction!

Comment: do you want something like selecting multiple rows?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to select multiple rows and then do something with them using an IBAction!

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UITableView`.  It has methods called `allowsMultipleSelection` and `indexPathsForSelectedRows`.

Comment: @yomo you can create an array of checked cells and show the check mark accordingly, just use `cellForRowIndexAtPath` delegate method.

Comment: @vaibhav Can you show me please?

Comment: [Plenty of examples available you can try with these](https://www.google.co.in/search?site=&source=hp&ei=khTsV9XjHo2evQS7u4iIAQ&q=save+checkmark+uitableview+ios&oq=save+checkmark+ui&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.1.0i22i30k1l2.53121.61540.0.65536.19.17.1.0.0.0.2388.9564.6-2j0j2j2.6.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-hp..12.7.9592.3..35i39k1j0i22i10i30k1.fb8bJGqe14M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

This code will show tick mark on your selected row.

You also have to use an array that maps the checked cells and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you have to verify if the accessoryType should be checked or not.

Then on your button action you can do your code with selected rows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added code, please help. I can only select one row, I want to select more than one!

Comment: i have edited the code use only this one!

Comment: I haven't declared selectedCell??

Comment: check now i have updated

Comment: selectedIndexes are not declared here!

Comment: That is a mutable array only you need to declare it global not within this function.

Comment: What is the code for declaring it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124457/discussion-between-satish-mavani-and-yomo).

Comment: in .h file of your view controller, add this:

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*selectedIndexes;